# If $g(x)$ is a polynomial in $GF(q)$, then $[g(x)]^q$ = $g(x^q)$.

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

If $g(x)$ is a polynomial in $GF(q)$, then $[g(x)]^q$ = $g(x^q)$.

I came across this statement as lemma 2.1 in [Factoring polynomials over large finite fields, ER Berlekamp](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-1970-0276200-X).

The author also mentions that this Lemma is discussed among the others in two other publications. However, I could not find adequate proofs there either. The books just state them as fact.

Is there something obvious here that I am missing that can be used to prove this statement?

Comment: Let $F$ be a field of order $q$. What is considered obvious, whether or not it is obvious to you, is that in $F[x]$, the $q$-th power map is additive on $F[x]$ and $a^q = a$ for all $a$ in $F$.  For example, if $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ in $F[x]$ then $f(x)^q = (ax^2 + bx + c)^q = (ax^2)^q + (bx)^q + c^q = a^qx^{2q} + b^qx^q + c^q = a(x^q)^2 + b(x^q) + c = f(x^q)$.  This kind of result should be found almost anywhere there is a discussion of the theory of finite fields, especially when $q = p$ is a prime number: did you look in books on finite fields?

Comment: You should learn about fields and rings of positive characteristic $p$, where $p$ is a prime number, and why the $p$th power mapping on (commutative) rings of characteristic $p$ is an additive mapping. This is a fancy way of saying the integers $\binom{p}{k}$ are all divisible by $p$ for $1 \leq k \leq p-1$ when $p$ is prime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Show that the claim is true when $g$ is constant
2. Expand 1. to monomials
3. Show (e.g., using properties of binomial coefficients) that the claim is true for $g_1+g_2$ if it is true for $g_1$ and $g_2$.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be the best answer that relies solely on fundamental Field axioms and basic Binomial expansions.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

A finite field $\mathbf F_q$, where $a=p^n$ is a prime power, is the splitting field of the polynomial $X^q-X$, and the map from $\mathbf F_q$ to itself defined by $x\longmapsto x^q$ is the $n$-iterate of the *Frobenius automorphism* $x\longmapsto x^p$.